# How does an Antivirus with thousands of signatures scan a file in a very short time?

Tags: antivirus

What speed optimization techniques do antiviruses use today to scan a file, provided they have to check for all the signatures + the behavioral scan?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a antivirus programmer, but I think the scan engine scans through a file searching for known pattern inside. The greater number of patterns it can identify, the longer it will take to scan.

Optimization maybe similar to database optimization, with patterns indexing.

[Identification Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antivirus_software)